# Pandas split column whose entries are my own class

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe `A`.

It has a column `col`.

`A['col']` is a column whose each entry is of type my_class.

`'my_class'` has attributes `my_class.x` and `my_class.y`

I wish to break `A['col']` into `A['x']` and `A['y']`.

`A['col'].str_split()` wont work as the entries type is not a string buy `my_class`

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `transform`

```
df.col.transform(lambda k : pd.Series(k.__dict__))
```

---

Example:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

obj1 = A("foo1", "bar1")
obj2 = A("foo2", "bar2")

df = pd.DataFrame({"col": [obj1, obj2]})

    col
0   <__main__.A object at 0x116de7b00>
1   <__main__.A object at 0x116de7438>
```

Then

```
df.col.transform(lambda k : pd.Series(k.__dict__))

    a       b
0   foo1    bar1
1   foo2    bar2
```